# How do I flip a byte array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, byte

I'm trying to find a php equivalent for this js function below:

Original JS function:

```
function getAddrCheckSum(addr: Buffer, isContract? : boolean): Hex {
    const addrPre20 = addr.slice(0, 20);
    const _checkSum = blake2b(addrPre20, null, ADDR_CHECK_SUM_SIZE);
    const checkSum = Buffer.from(_checkSum);

    if (!isContract) {
        return checkSum.toString('hex');
    }

    const newCheckSum = [];
    checkSum.forEach(function (byte) {
        newCheckSum.push(byte ^ 0xFF);
    });

    return Buffer.from(newCheckSum).toString('hex');
}
```

PHP implementation:

```
include_once('./lib/Blake2b.php');

function getAddrCheckSum($address, $isContract) {
    $ADDR_CHECK_SUM_SIZE = 5;

    $addrPre20 = substr($address, 0, 20);
    $blake2b = new Blake2b($ADDR_CHECK_SUM_SIZE); #<- blake object initialized with size=5
    $checkSum = $blake2b->hash($addrPre20);

    return $checkSum;
    if (!isContract) {
        return strval($checkSum);
    }
```

How can I rewrite this part below in php?

```
$newCheckSum = [];
//checkSum.forEach(function (byte) { 
// newCheckSum.push(byte ^ 0xFF);    
//});

return strval($newCheckSum);
}
```

Also, am I doing this right by replacing the js toString by php strval?
and, do I need to find an equivalent of "Buffer.from(...,'hex')" for php
instead of just assigning it to a variable?

Comment: Please provide an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Here is the problem description:


"Take characters between 6-45 of Literal Address as the 20-byte Address Body and check:

    If the hex string of checksum of Address Body matches the characters from 46 to 55 in Literal Address, set 0 to Type Flag as the address is a user address.
    If the hex string of flipped checksum of Address Body is the same as the 46th to 55th chars of Literal Address, set 1 to Type Flag as the address is a contract address.

The checksum is calculated by taking a 5-byte hash on the basis of Address Body."

Comment: Example data:

DBG: Literal addr: vite_24d6313a1ee1bcd8e979565a39a9c6f4decc8a1be01a5debee

DBG: Address body: 24d6313a1ee1bcd8e979565a39a9c6f4decc8a1b

DBG: Body current chcksum: e01a5debee

Answer (score 2):

`bin2hex` is your friend. Assuming that `$checkSum` is the hash in binary form and `$isContract` is boolean then just XOR `$checkSum` with the corresponding number of `\xFF` characters.
Here is a verbose version:

```php
if (!$isContract)
{
 return bin2hex($checkSum);
}
else
{
 $newCheckSum = $checkSum ^ str_pad("", strlen($checkSum), "\xFF");
 return bin2hex($newCheckSum);
}
```

And a short one:

```php
return bin2hex
(
  !$isContract ? $checkSum: $checkSum ^ str_pad("", strlen($checkSum), "\xFF")
);
```